# How to connect Spark Structured Streaming to blob/file creation events from Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 or Blob Storage

Tags: apache-spark, azure-storage, spark-structured-streaming, azure-hdinsight, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am new to Spark Structured Streaming and its concepts. Was reading through the documentation for Azure HDInsight cluster [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/spark/apache-spark-structured-streaming-overview) and it's mentioned that the structured streaming applications run on HDInsight cluster and connects to streaming data from .. Azure Storage, or Azure Data Lake Storage. I was looking at how to get started with the streaming listening to new file created events from the storage or ADLS. The spark [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#quick-example) does provide an example, but i am looking for how to tie up streaming with the blob/file creation event, so that I can store the file content in a queue from my spark job. It will be great if anyone can help me out on this.

Comment: Will prefer getting pointers, than downvoting thinking I didnt do research. I reached out to stack overflow because of the experts here and not much documentation online around how to connect blob/azure storage events to spark streaming.

Answer (score 1):

happy to help you on this, but can you be more precise with the requirement. Yes, you can run the Spark Structured Streaming jobs on Azure HDInsight. Basically mount the azure blob storage to cluster and then you can directly read the data available in the blob.

```
val df = spark.read.option("multiLine", true).json("PATH OF BLOB")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @chaitra k. Yes I was looking for the same. I was looking to see how to listen to events from blob storage/adls gen2. By saying mount the azure blob storage to cluster, you mean to connect to the blob and have a long running job ?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Data Lake Gen2 (ADL2) has been released for Hadoop 3.2 only. Open Source Spark 2.4.x supports Hadoop 2.7 and if you compile it yourself Hadoop 3.1. Spark 3 will support Hadoop 3.2, but it's not released yet (only preview release).

Databricks offers support for ADL2 natively.

My solution to tackle this problem was to manually patch and compile Spark 2.4.4 with Hadoop 3.2 to be able to use the ADL2 libs from Microsoft.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Since ADLS Gen2 is based on the blob storage , i am assuming it should be the same as connecting to a blob storage. The underlying file path also takes the same path as the blob storage.

Comment: ADLS Gen2 is different to blob storage and needs a specific driver. The advantage of ADLS Gen2 is atomic directory rename that won't be offered by blob storage. Blob storage files aren't organized in hierarchial structures (e.g. directories) but as key value pair. When you rename a key, the "sub keys" won't be renamed. So the blob storage driver simulates directory rename by renaming all sub keys which is not atomic. Spark relies on atomic rename to guarantee exactly once semantics by writing to a temp dir and rename it to move to the final destination which actually commits the microbatch.

Comment: that makes sense. I was also looking at the atomic rename capability of ADLS Gen2.  If I use the blob storage , is there a workaround around the above to gaurantee exactly once semantics for the blob storage.